# Luigi: TypeError: ... missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python, luigi

I have the following Luigi setup

```py
import luigi


class RootTask(luigi.WrapperTask):
    def requires(self):
        yield RunAndReport(
            task=TaskA()
        )


class RunAndReport(luigi.WrapperTask):
    task = luigi.TaskParameter()

    def requires(self):
        yield self.task
        yield Report(
            input=self.task.input_file(),
            output=self.task.output_file()
        )


class Report(luigi.Task):
    pass


class TaskA(luigi.Task):

    def input_file(self):
        return 'file://opt/something_in.txt'

    def output_file(self):
        return 'file://opt/something_out.txt'
```

and I am getting the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/luigi-3.0.3-py3.9.egg/luigi/worker.py", line 401, in check_complete
    is_complete = task.complete()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/luigi-3.0.3-py3.9.egg/luigi/task.py", line 822, in complete
    return all(r.complete() for r in flatten(self.requires()))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/luigi-3.0.3-py3.9.egg/luigi/task.py", line 883, in flatten
    for result in iterator:
  File "/opt/my_file.py", line 48, in requires
    input_file=self.task.input_file(),
TypeError: input_file() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

As if TaskA is not instantiated and only the class definition is passed. Is this some kind of weird Python lazy initialization thing?

Comment: Please do not use reserved terms like `input` as a variable. This is not related to the question (or might not matter much in classes) but it is not a good practice.

Comment: could it be that `self.task` is a class? and so you have forgotten to instantiate it such as `self.task()` -> `self.task().input_file()`?

Comment: @Matiiss yes. most probably this is the case but why? I am passing an instantiation of `TaskA` using `TaskA()`

Comment: @Matiiss if I do this `self.task().input_file()` then it fails in other parts of the code with error `TypeError: 'TaskC' object is not callable`.. SInce I'm using this pattern to report many tasks, It only happens with TaskA

Comment: well, I am not familiar with `luigi`, but you can also try to make those methods `@staticmethods` and remove that `self` argument from them

Answer (score 2):

TaskParameter() takes a class, not an instance.

I found this alternative which works with some instances, but it looks like it's not really set up to work that way. It's probably easier to set up something that can work with just passing the Task class and perhaps sending the other values as additional parameters.

https://github.com/spotify/luigi/issues/1945#issuecomment-291759850

```
import luigi
import json

class SubtaskParameter(luigi.Parameter):
    def serialize(self, val):
        return json.dumps((val.get_task_family(), val.param_args))

    def parse(self, val):
        (cls, params) = json.loads(val)
        cls = luigi.task_register.Register.get_task_cls(cls)
        return cls(*params)
```

Comment: `TaskParameter() takes a class, not an instance.` This is nasty....

Answer (score 0):

What I actually ended up doing was:

```py
import luigi


class RootTask(luigi.WrapperTask):
    def requires(self):
        task_a = TaskA()
        yield task_a
        yield Report(
            input=task_a.input_file(),
            output=task_a.output_file()
        )


class Report(luigi.Task):
    pass


class TaskA(luigi.Task):

    def input_file(self):
        return 'file://opt/something_in.txt'

    def output_file(self):
        return 'file://opt/something_out.txt'
```

There is some repetition but it works